# Active/Hover State using Javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time coding an active state for a little accordion style menu I'm working on.  I have the hover transitions in place and the menu will stay open when clicked, however, I lose my styling after the user clicks and moves the mouse off the menu.

I'd like the styling to remain until the next item is clicked, and so on.

Example of what I'm working on here: http://codepen.io/Sektion66/pen/dviJG

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the header is clicked, you can use `toggleClass` to give it a class. Then, you just use some CSS like you're already doing. Instead of styling on hover, you just style on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.dd-header").click(function() {
        var $el = $(this).find('ul.hidden');
        var $opened = $('.toggledDown').not($el);
        $opened.toggleClass('toggledDown');
        $opened.slideToggle();
        $el.toggleClass('toggledDown');
        $el.slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('toggleHeader');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggleHeader{
    border-left: 10px solid @blue;
    background-color: #000;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Evan.  I've been trying stuff like this all night, and it seems like it should work, but I'm still having problems for whatever reason.  Perhaps my brain is just fried!  I'll explore this example more to see if I can't get it working.

Comment: After walking away for awhile and looking at this with a fresh mind...   it got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: @user2284741 I'm glad, that's usually all it takes :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to toggle the the class that defines a selected element on the element.

```
$('dd-main').click(function () { $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected'); } );
```

This will remove styling from any other selected element then add the class to the new element that was clicked

Comment: Hey Justin.  Thanks for the quick reply.  I understand the basic idea of the example code you gave me, I'm not exactly sure how it fits into what I currently have though. I'm very new to using javascript unfortunately...   thanks again though.